# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError can not load dll

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface

Hello i am gettin lang `UnsatisfiedLinkError` with JRegistryKey. I am using Netbeans 8.0.2 on Windows 7 32bit .The jRegistryKey.dll is in my Projects root folder and in my Path variable.
I get the Exception here:

```
 RegistryKey.initialize("jRegistryKey.dll");
  RegistryKey key = new RegistryKey(RootKey.HKLM,"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\CheckpointDRG");
  Iterator<RegistryKey> subkey = key.subkeys();
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: ca.beq.util.win32.registry.RegistryKey.testInitialized()V
    at ca.beq.util.win32.registry.RegistryKey.testInitialized(Native Method)
    at ca.beq.util.win32.registry.RegistryKey.initialize(RegistryKey.java:294)
    at gotdb.Importer.OpenConnection(Importer.java:95)
    at gotdb.GotDB.main(GotDB.java:19)
Java Result: 1
```